# Wordpress running on Amazon EC2 Domain Mapping Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, domain-mapping

Have setup an EC2 instance and finished installing wordpress and domain mapping. Everything works fine when I enter the domain http://domain.com. But when I click on any link to inner pages on the homepage, it redirects to 54.80.186.212/contact-us. How do I solve this problem.

I've an A record pointed to the Elastic IP of AWS for non-www version and another A record pointed to the same IP for WWW version. Both works fine but the inner pages don't. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your wordpress general setting and change your website cononical address.
just this!

Comment: Thanks, that works. The tutorial I followed didn't mention this.